# How to use Kerberos ticket in two Java applications?

Tags: authentication, kerberos, jaas

I hope I will be clear here: 
Let's a user authenticates to application A using Kerberos (the code uses the JAAS Krb5LoginModule). 
The client now needs to authenticate to Application B as well. 
The Kerberos ticket is still valid. 
How can I use I make sure that auhtentication flow to application B  will not try to create a new Kerberos ticket? 
When I use JAAS I perform:
`loginContext.login` 
 (I of course passed a callback handler to provider credentials and the name that is used as an index to the configuration, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/LoginContext.html#LoginContext%28java.lang.String,%20javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler%29) here), and of course Application A and application B run as different as different processes, 
 so the loginContext object is not shared between them. 
How can I reuse the valid kerberos ticket between the two applications which run in different processes, but the user uses the same credentials (same user@realm) 
Thanks

Comment: Application do not authenticate in general. Clients authenticate against an application. Please update your question to be understandable and I will try to help you.

Comment: Well, this is better but still incomplete. ARe you referrnig to the TGT or servce ticket?

Comment: I will try to elaborate - Application a is a java ee server which has web application which allows you to perform login. I use JAAS login module in order to perform kerberos authentication and then I query iunformation from LDAP server (using ActiveDirectory - so it's KDC + Ldap server). Appplication B is another client (but remote client) of the server described at A, so I would like that customers that login to the remote client will be to use the same tickets if they later on login using the web application of the server.

Comment: So, app A and B reside on the same physical machine and are webapps?

Comment: Yes. Of course customers may browse them remotely.

Comment: So you want client => A and client => B?

Comment: You have two types of clients: one is standalone web application, the other is web application within the context of the application server. I would like to reuse kerberos tickets if I login via client A and client B with the same credentials. I hope I am clear :)

Comment: These aren't clients these are targets. You obvious either do not know or cannot make a difference between a client (src/context initiator) and destination (target/context acceptor).

Answer (score 0):

If both applications are on the same physical/logical machine, share the same SPN and both are running under the machine account, yes you can reuse the service ticket until it expires. But those is actually handled by the browser. You will never mess with them anyway. Your SPNEGO acceptor does everything for you.

Comment: What happens if I access via two browsers on different machines?

Comment: This does not matter, the clients will obtain appropriate service tickets for the target servers as long as Kerberos setup is fine. I recommend you to read how Kerberos really work. Otherwise you won't unterstand what your problem is and what you really want. I am having a hard time to understand your real intention/problem.